# Is there any way to automatically generate proxy class for android in eclipse for web service if I have web service url?

Tags: java, android, web-services

Is there any way to automatically  generate proxy class for android in eclipse for web service if I have web service url ?
I found ksoap2, but there I need to know method name and parameters to add to request, I can manually wrap but if there is already automatic way I can avoid bugs in my code
I know similar stuff can be done in Visual Studio/C#, where you get class with all methods like webservice.

Comment: Have you considered Heinz Kabutz's [DynamicObjectAdapterFactory](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue108.html).

Answer (score 0):

When you say "for android" you mean for use in an android app? I haven't used it in some time, but I think you can use [SoapUI](http://java.dzone.com/tips/generating-client-java-code). That article is a few years old, but should still be possible. There are also tools (wsdl2java) that come with Apache axis, and cxf that you can use.